# Ruby on Rails skip update callback on specific method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, callback

In my Student model I trigger a method `after_update`, but the problem is I have to save within the method. This results in an infinite recursive loop:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

after_update :delete_inactive_student_schedules

def delete_inactive_student_schedules
  if self.status_was == active and self.status == paused
    self.missing_schedule_at = nil
    self.save!
    self.schedules.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Is there a way to skip the update callback after the save within the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update_columns to update colums without triggering callbacks or validations.

So in your case

```
if self.status_was == active and self.status == paused
  self.update_columns(:missing_schedule_at => nil)
  self.schedules.destroy_all
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns